# Why don't yahoo pipes fetch a custom URL for freelancer.com?

Tags: yahoo-pipes

i want to build a feed for freelancer.com , i did the following , pipes.yahoo.com/xkid/freelancer11 , i don't really understand why doesn't it work, it build me a URL like http://www.freelancer.com/rss/job_Amazon-Web-Services.xml but , when i try to fetch its feed it doesn't seem to get any items , but the URL works if i put it directly into fetch feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the **Fetch Feed** module, not the **Fetch Site Feed** module you currently have.